# Store properties or fields of a class in a dictionary

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to create a window where the user can map fields from an XML file to fields or properties of a class and later access the mapping for importing the same XML structure. For example I have the order class:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public string OrderId { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the XML:

```
<Order>
  <Header>
    <OrderNo>4711</OrderNo>
    <OrderStatus>20</OrderStatus>
    <OrderConfirmed>1</OrderConfirmed>
    <OrderReference>test</OrderReference>
  </Header>
</Order>
```

Now my idea is to use a simple Linq to XML method:

```
    var ordersInXml = xDoc.Root
                        .Elements("Header")
                        .Select(x => new Order()
                        {
                            OrderId = (string)x.Descendants("OrderNo").First().Value,
                            OrderStatus = (string)x.Descendants("OrderStatus").First().Value

                        })
                    .ToList();
```

I want to be able to somehow build a method which maps the attributes of the XML to the fields of my class. For example access a dictionary in my Linq to XML code?
I have no good idea how to achieve that. Any better ideas?

Comment: So, the classes will be fixed but the xml will vary regarding how it maps?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: It sounds really too broad for an SO question. Conceptually, you can simply store a "mapping" that has a string for class property name and a string for the xml node name. In LINQ, use the node name instead of hard-coding "OrderNo", etc. However, if your xml becomes hierarchical or may contain namespaces it gets more complicated.